# Java Inner Classes NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, drjava

I am writing a short Java program that is supposed to take in a list of 5 integers and assign each to one of 6 members.  I want to maximize the number of members who are receiving a value between their `min` and `max` values.
Anyways, for some reason that is unknown to me, my private `member` class seems to be throwing a NullPointerException, but I am at a complete loss as to why.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class assign {
    private class member {
        private String name;
        private int min;
        private int max;
        public member(String name, int min, int max) {
            this.name = name;
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
    }

    public member[] members = {
        new member("Phil", 1, 20),
        new member("Molly", 1, 20),
        new member("Connor", 21, 40),
        new member("Sam", 21, 40),
        new member("Dan", 41, 60),
        new member("Theresa", 41, 60)
    };

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
        String s = StdIn.readLine();
        String[] temp = s.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            nums.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
        }
        ArrayList<member> mems = new ArrayList<member>(Arrays.asList(members));

        for (int n : nums) {
            for (member m : mems) {
                if (n > m.min && n < m.max) {
                    System.out.println(m.name + " : " + n);
                    nums.remove(n);
                    mems.remove(m);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int n : nums) {
            member m = mems.remove(0);
            System.out.println(m.name + " : " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

**From OP's comment:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)
```

Comment: You should really go back and read the FAQ. If you need help with code you've written, you need to post under which conditions, what you expect to actually happen, any stack traces, etc.

Comment: You need to indicate which line throws the NPE.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Comment: There's no obvious issue without our knowing which line throws the exception. A variable on that line is null. Show the complete exception message in your question, and try to find the line in your code that is indicated in the exception message, and comment it for us.

Comment: the short answer is I have no idea what line is throwing the exception. You can see the error message for yourself.

Comment: Again, please post the entire message in the question itself, not part of the message in a comment. Also, and again, as per your previously deleted question, **your current main method should be static.**

Comment: Error messages are messages. You can read them once yourself, and enable line numbers in your editor.

Comment: Honestly, have you used a debugger to step through your code?  Have you monitored your variables as you step through to see if they are being set to the values you expect?  Have you tried setting breakpoints so you can examine the states of objects at key points? Why don't you just try doing that first.

Comment: @scottb: he can't use a debugger nor step through his code because it won't run. See my answer to see why.

Comment: This is a bug in DrJava.  Your `main` should have been `static`.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911004/nullpointerexcetion-native-method-accessor-hashing-words-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm betting that your error is that **your current main method is not static**:

```
// this should be a static method
public void main(String[] args) {
  // ...
}
```

Solution: make the main method static as it should be.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // ...
}
```

Once you fix this, you'll see other errors, mainly that you're trying to access non-static things in a static way. To fix this, you'll want to give your assign class (please rename this Assign so that it starts with an upper case letter) public methods to call, and then have your main method create an Assign instance and call these methods.

For instance here:

```
ArrayList<member> mems = new ArrayList<member>(Arrays.asList(members));
```

You're trying to use the non-static members array in a static context. You will want to only handle it inside your Assign class, inside of its public methods. Either that or make `members` static.

Comment: It really begs the question how is this program being run??

Comment: How could he run it without a static main? Seems to me that this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @clwhisk: it's not. The exception is thrown and it quits.

Comment: Oh, and some custom compiler that expects you to not make that mistake or notice quickly.

Comment: @clwhisk: Exactly. Very nice pick up!

Comment: @bmargulies: how can this not be an answer when I believe it to be **the** answer? Do you have a better answer that explains that exception stacktrace? If so, please share, and I'll gladly delete this one.

Comment: It's on a line between 'inspired guess' as an answer and 'could it be that this is true?' as a clarifying question/comment.

Answer (score 0):

First big question like every one how is your code running without a static main ?

Your code has lot of flows,
Kindly revisit the logic and try to run different test cases against your code (valid ones and then invalid ones). This is a good problem statement.

As an e.g

```
for (int n : nums) {
            for (member m : mems) {
                if (n > m.min && n < m.max) {
                    System.out.println(m.name + " : " + n);
                    nums.remove(n);
                    mems.remove(m);
                }
            }
        }
```

You have **ConcurrentModificationException** waiting to happen.

Are you sure you want to have this line :
 nums.remove(n);
**IndexOutOfBoundsException**.